# is it okay for a functional component to have multiple functions within?

Tags: reactjs, components

I am working on writing function based react components with useState.
My questions are =
A. Should my component ideally consist of 1 single function?
B. Is this "bad" coding to have multiple functions nested within the parent function?
C. Are there ways to simplify this?
D. How can I make the search bar clear, without reseting state?

I'm fairly new to react, so I want to be sure I have a good understanding of its logic. Thank you for your help!

This component will eventually become a search component. Once the user enters a term, i'd like that word to map to the card... but right now I just want to know if my code is considered "correct"

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Form.css';
import Input from './Input';
import Card from '../Card/Card';


export default function SearchForm(){

    // establishing hook

    const [state, setState] = useState();

    // takes user input to set the state variable

    function handleChange(e) {
        setState(e.target.value);
    }

    // log state to console

    function submit (e) {
        console.log(state);    
    }

    return(
        <div className="form-group"> 

            <Input onChange={handleChange}/>

            <button onClick={submit}>
                Submit
            </button>

            <Card>
                <h1>{state}</h1>
            </Card>

        </div>
    )
};
```

Comment: yes its ok to have multiple functions

Answer (score 1):

It's OK but since `handleChange` is calling `setState` (the *setter* from the hook) - you should really use a custom hook.  Something like this, outside of the component, should work:

```
const useHandleChange = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(**default-value**)
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setState(e.target.value)
  }
  return [state, handleChange]
}
```

Inside of component you can consume that hook like so:

```
const [state, handleChange] = useHandleChange()
```

Comment: Since I'm new to React, it's probably a dumb question, but anyway. Why is it necessary or better to use a custom hook?